# How to create a two column pick list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

I want to be able to have a pick list with two columns setup in a worksheet and pick from that list in another worksheet to populate two columns.

Pick List Sheet would look like this

```
A  Item 1     Item 2
B  Johnson    22
C  Jones      45
```

Destination Sheet would look like this

```
A  Item 1  Item 2
B  Drop down to choose Johnson from the pick list, Item 2 is populated with '22'
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Original question looked more like hlookup, but edited is same, just vlookup
Dropdown list is done with Data-Validation.

```
dest!B2 =vlookup(A2;picksheet!$A$B;2;0)
```

[GoogleDocs demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aueb2Yt6gVjpdFYwX1NQWml5SHVCYkQ0eVJnUW4zV2c)

Answer (score -1):

=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(D14, Sheet2!A:B, 2, 0)), "", VLOOKUP('User Information'!D14, Sheet2!A:B, 2, 0))

This is what worked for me. I know nothing about excel formulas but what Elhana mentioned i wasnt able to use it, may be i was doing something wrong.  god knows where this formula came from but it worked.